# data from database not returning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react file, I need to check if my data variable is undefined or not in my DisplayCharacterDetails() function. However, when the function runs, I do not get the data.

When I console.log(data.character), I get the following:

{__typename: "Character", id: "5f4be9d5652cd07eda934rt6", name: "Iron Man", studio: "Marvel", affiliation: "Avengers", …}

However, when I do data.name, nothing prints out.

```
const {loading, data} = useQuery(getSingleCharacterQuery, {
    variables: {id: props.characterID}
});

function DisplayCharacterDetails() {
    console.log(data.character)
    if(data) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{data.name}</h2>
                <p>{data.studio}</p>
                <p>{data.affiliation}</p>
                <p>{data.protrayedBy}</p>
                <p>{data.creator.name}</p>
                <p>All characters by this creator: </p>
                <ul className="other-characters">
                { data.creator.characters.map(item =>{
                   return <li key={item.id}> {item.name}</li>
                })
                }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (
            <div>
                No Character Selected
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try explicitly checking if the value is ```undefined``` or not ? e.g ```if(data!==undefined){...}```

Comment: yes I have, it still doesnt work

Comment: Could you please edit the question, to add the output of  ```console.log(data)```, might help in figuring out the issue.

Comment: There are three places where `.name` is used. I suggest you expand your debugging search beyond the first case.

Comment: @jas305 That was a bad edit.. Why did you remove the error message? That is important information. Also, that console log output is not enough, please expand the object and copy the whole thing.

Comment: the error message is gone after @pawel's answer

Comment: Ok then you now have a new question, you shouldn't make updates that change the main part of the question. Now anyone reading this in the future will be confused by powel's answer.

Comment: im sorry, i wanted to delete this but stack overflow didnt allow me since people invested time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like to get the character object:

```
Console.log(data.character);
```

To get the character name:

```
console.log(data.character.name);
```

Looks like name is a property of character according to your object...

Answer (score 0):

The error can be not only in `data.name` but also in `<p>{data.creator.name}</p>` or in `<li key={item.id}> {item.name}</li>`. You can use the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining to prevent reading from undefined property.

```
const {loading, data} = useQuery(getSingleCharacterQuery, {
    variables: {id: props.characterID}
});

function DisplayCharacterDetails() {
    console.log(data.character)
    if(data) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{data.name}</h2>
                <p>{data.studio}</p>
                <p>{data.affiliation}</p>
                <p>{data.protrayedBy}</p>
                <p>{data.creator?.name}</p>
                <p>All characters by this creator: </p>
                <ul className="other-characters">
                { data.creator.characters.map(item =>{
                   return <li key={item.id}> {item?.name}</li>
                })
                }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (
            <div>
                No Character Selected
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this only a list of supposition.  You could make as comment.  Please make a real example with explanation.

Comment: you have to have 50 of reputation to add the comment

Comment: Lack of reputation isn't a reason to misuse the answer section. You could turn this into an answer if you want, you just have to remove the speculation and explain what you believe will solve it and why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was to check if data.character is null or not. So, we need 2 if statements like so:

```
if(data && data.character) {
     
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>name: {data.character.name}</h2>
                <p>{data.character.studio}</p>
                <p>{data.character.affiliation}</p>
                <p>{data.character.protrayedBy}</p>
                <p>{data.character.creator.name}</p>
                <p>All characters by this creator: </p>
                {/* <ul className="other-characters">
                { data.creator.characters.map(item =>{
                   return <li key={item.id}> {item.name}</li>
                })
                }
                </ul> */}
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: You don't need two if statements, you can do it in one: `if (data && data.character)`

Comment: yes, that works too, it's more efficient, I will fix my answer